# Python 2.7.6 TLSv1.2 in requests

Tags: python, python-requests, tls1.2

I use python version 2.7.6 and need to make a request using TLSv1.2.
I tried something like this to specify the version of tls:

```
class SslAdapter():
def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
    self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                   maxsize=maxsize,
                                   block=block,
                                   ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
s=requests.Session() 
s.mount('https://', SslAdapter())
s.get('https://google.com',verify=False)
```

But in debugger i see that version of TLS in request is TLSv1.0.
Can you suggest how to properly specify TLS version?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are running into

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2'
```

That's because TLSv1_2 wasn't added until [2.7.9](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1443704). You can use [backports.ssl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backports.ssl/0.0.9).
Once you have that installed, replace your

```
import ssl
```

with

```
import backports.ssl as ssl
```

Comment: @Tommy were you able to find any solution?